# How to update time in a timer

Tags: java, android

I want to make a countdown timer and i want to update the time every second. I have create an update timer but it still don't work.

Can anyone tell me what i have  wrong?

This is my code:

```
public void updateTimer(int secondsLeft) {

    int minutes = secondsLeft / 60;
    int seconds = secondsLeft * 60;

    String secondString = Integer.toString(seconds);

    if (seconds <= 9) {
        secondString = "0" + secondString;
    }

    time.setText(Integer.toString(minutes) + ":" + secondString);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by don't work ? It crashes ? (then what is the error/exception you obtain ?) It does not do what you want ? (Then describe what happened, what were you expecting).

Comment: Why are you multiplying the number of second by 60 ?

Comment: Please provide the error message from the logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the modulo operator % to calculate the number of second properly.
Here is your function fixed:

```
public void updateTimer(int secondsLeft) {

        int minutes = secondsLeft / 60;
        int seconds = secondsLeft % 60;

        String secondString = Integer.toString(seconds);

        if (seconds <= 9) {
            secondString = "0" + secondString;
        }

        time.setText(Integer.toString(minutes) + ":" + secondString);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer now i try